# Get window handle in godot? C#

Tags: c#, mono, godot

How do I get the window handle in Godot (C# mono)

I've been a WPF and Winforms developer for quite some time but I just started Godot and I am wondering since I need to make modifications to the window.

Comment: What modification are you trying do to? Godot has means to manipulate its window (which would also be portable), and its own widget solution. So there might be a way to do what you want in Godot already. Thus, asking for the window handle instead of asking for what you actually want to do seems to me like a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Anyway, I answered the question as posted. And I remind you that the Godot window is not a WinForm nor WPF window.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `hWnd` of the Godot Window, you can use this function:

```
OS.get_native_handle(OS.WINDOW_HANDLE)
```

From C# that looks like this:

```
OS.GetNativeHandle(OS.HandleType.WindowHandle)
```